# how dow i get a String[][] to an Arraylist<String[][]>

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, arraylist

I have a 2-dimensional array and I want to convert it into a Arraylist. How should I organize such list?

For instance when I have array

```
String[][] things={{"dog", "cat", "wolf"},
                   {"carrot", "apple", "banana"}};
```

I would like to have list

```
List<what is proper type?> Galg = ...
```

which will allow me to get row indexed as `x` and get item from that row with index `y`?

Comment: The question does not make sense because the first type has 2-dimensions, and the second type has 3-dimensions. Also .. *include a language tag* and remove any irrelevant tags.

Comment: Maybe the question does not makes sence cause i am doing things wrong. Perhaps this is also why i ask the question. but thx anyway.

Comment: Can you give example of content of that list and how would you like to use it?

Comment: For now I am voting to put your question on hold because it is unclear what you want to achieve. I will retract my vote or vote to reopen this question when you provide more informations about how would you like to use that list and what data should it contain.

Comment: What is not clear? i just want an Arraylist containing.{"dog", "cat", "wolf"} and { "carrot", "apple", "banana"} . Why is this not clear i dont understand?

Comment: And you got answer which does exactly what you said, but you seem not to like it without explaining what is wrong with posted answer: "I want the Arraylist to be exactly the same as the array" is very vague.

Comment: I suspect what you may be looking for lists of lists, but I can't post it as answer because it is only a guess, and on Stack Overflow we want to focus on valid answers, not guesses.

Comment: Posting example of how would you like to use such list could add some light to the problem and reduce amount of possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry i am a noob, so i dont understand this, but i try. but so far i also dont understand the commands :-( not your fault of course , just stating a fact. \Sorry for my nooby behaviour.

Comment: Lets start from beginning. What value you expect to get when you call `Galg.get(0)`? What should this value represent/contain? Entire array, first row, or maybe first element in first row?

Comment: I expect {"dog","cat", "wolf"}

Comment: So now we know that you don't want `List<String[][]>` since such list must store two dimensional arrays, but you want list which will be able to store rows. Which means you want something more like `List<String[]>` (one dimension, not two).

Comment: Now when you get that `{"dog", "cat", "wolf"}` row, how would you like to get element like `cat`? Do you want `list.get(0)[1]` or `list.get(0).get(1)`?

Comment: Ok i guess so. But on Galg.get(1) i expect { "carrot", "apple", "banana"} and on something like Galg.get(1,1) i just expect apple?

Comment: Lists doesn't support `get(x,y)`, just like arrays doesn't support `[x,y]`. In arrays you also must call `[x][y]` and for nested lists you must call `get(x).get(y)`.

Comment: Ok i understand the last  command.

Comment: The proper type would be `List<List<String>>` or `List<String[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` or better lets program on interfaces rather than actual type and make our reference more general (which also means flexible because it can handle many lists, not only `ArrayList`) with

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

or since Java 7  we can shorten it using diamond operator and let generic type be inferred

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can create it via code like

```
String[][] things={{"dog", "cat", "wolf"},{ "carrot", "apple", "banana"}};
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String[] row : things){
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(row)));
}
```

and use it like

```
System.out.println(list.get(1).get(2));//get row indexed as 1, 
                                       //and from it item indexed as 2
```

---

Try to think of list as one dimensional array. Actually all arrays are one dimensional, because two dimensional arrays are simply one dimensional arrays which elements are other one dimensional arrays (you are nesting one dimensional arrays).

So your array

```
A{     
  [0] -> B{ 
           [0] -> "dog", 
           [1] -> "cat", 
           [2] -> "wolf"
         }
  [1] -> C{ 
           [0] -> "carrot", 
           [1] -> "apple", 
           [2] -> "banana"
         }
}
```

So we have one dimensional array `A` which contains other one dimensional arrays `B` and `C`.

Same is possible for list. You can nest them just like arrays are nested.

```
ListA{     
      [0] -> ListB{ 
                   [0] -> "dog", 
                   [1] -> "cat", 
                   [2] -> "wolf"
             }
      [1] -> ListC{ 
                   [0] -> "carrot", 
                   [1] -> "apple", 
                   [2] -> "banana"
             }
}
```

So we can have List< of Lists< of String>> which is written as `List<List<String>`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can just do

```
Galg.add(things);
```

But, perhaps you need an `ArrayList<String[]>` instead? In that case, you can use `Arrays.asList`:

```
ArrayList<String[]> Galg = new ArrayList<String[]>();
Galg.addAll(Arrays.asList(things));
```

Comment: I want the Arraylist to be exactly the same as the array, could you give me a example please?

Comment: Then, use the second example. You can add more items to the list later, for instance with `Galg.add(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });`.